# want to ask if there is a way that I can display a field from another content type to a field of another content type

Tags: nodes, entities

Im quite new to drupal (7) and want to ask if there is a way that I can display a field from another content type to a field of another content type and applying condition at the same time?

Here is the scenario:

I have created content types: Courses and Course schedules

I will be creating more than 50 contents for courses (containing their description, objectives etc as fields).

I will create different course schedule contents (data in here changes regularly including fields like time, date, venue, etc).

What i want to accomplish is to display the course article with a field that is linked to the courses schedule content, thus showing the available class sched data for each course.

I dont want to do it with views because im thinking it would be tedious to create a view for each course.

Is there a best way you can recommended to accomplish this? or is there a module that does this?

Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module for accomplishing your requirements.

On the "Courses" content type you will add a field type entity reference which refer to the "Course Schedules" content type.

Then in the "Courses" content type Manage Display, You can choose that the referred node link to appear, I think you can also choose that the rendered node to appear.

Comment: Additionally, using Inline Entity Form (https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form), you can create and manage the Schedule from the Course or vice verse.